# SQL RN Counts in two CTEs and still cannot get precise row needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server. Using SSMS as the SQL editor.

I have a query that gets me more than the data I need. Essentially, I just need to show the results that tell me the first-ever date on a customer's account where a fill was sent. And if the customer pauses shipments and restarts then just the very first restart fill date. I have been working on this query using two `CROSS APPLY`s, one `CROSS APPLY` and one CTE, etc.

I get close, but only on the first row. The last column on row 2 should be a date and on row 3 should be NULL as we did not send anything after the customer ended his pause date. Here is the code I have so far.

The three tables are:

CUSTOMER:

| CUST_NO | SERIES_NO | ACCT_OPENED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| W125 | 1001 | 12/1/2020 |

FILL_DATE_HX:

| CUST_NO | SERIES_NO | FILL_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| W125 | 1001 | 12/2/2020 |
| W125 | 1001 | 12/15/2020 |
| W125 | 1001 | 12/28/2020 |
| W125 | 1001 | 1/16/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 2/10/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 2/28/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 3/15/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 4/10/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 4/29/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 5/12/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 5/27/2021 |

PAUSE_HX:

| CUST_NO | SERIES_NO | PAUSE_START_DATE | PAUSE_END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W125 | 1001 | 1/7/2021 | 1/15/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 4/19/2021 | 4/28/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 6/2/2021 | 6/8/2021 |

The Query I have so far is:

```
WITH restart_fill_date AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        fill.FILL_DATE,
        cus.CUST_NO,
        cus.SERIES_NO,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cus.CUST_NO ORDER BY cus.CUST_NO, PAUSE_HX.PAUSE_START_DATE ) RN
    FROM 
        Fills.dbo.FILL_DATE_HX fill
    LEFT JOIN 
        Fills.dbo.customer cus ON fill.CUST_NO = cus.CUST_NO
    LEFT JOIN 
        Fills.dbo.PAUSE_HX ON cus.CUST_NO = PAUSE_HX.CUST_NO
), first_fill_date AS 
(
    SELECT
        fill.FILL_DATE,
        cus.CUST_NO,
        cus.SERIES_NO,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cus.CUST_NO  ORDER BY cus.CUST_NO, fill.FILL_DATE) rn_2
    FROM 
        Fills.dbo.FILL_DATE_HX fill
    LEFT JOIN 
        CUSTOMER cus ON fill.CUST_NO = cus.CUST_NO
) 
SELECT DISTINCT
    cus.CUST_NO, 
    cus.SERIES_NO, 
    cus.ACCT_OPENED_DATE,
    CASE 
        WHEN cus.ACCT_OPENED_DATE <= first_fill_date.FILL_DATE 
            THEN first_fill_date.FILL_DATE 
    END FIRST_SENT_DATE,
    PAUSE_HX.PAUSE_START_DATE,  
    PAUSE_HX.PAUSE_END_DATE,
    CASE 
        WHEN PAUSE_HX.PAUSE_END_DATE <= restart_fill_date.FILL_DATE 
            THEN restart_fill_date.FILL_DATE 
    END RESTART_REPLACEMENT_DATE
FROM 
    Fills.dbo.customer cus
LEFT JOIN 
    Fills.dbo.PAUSE_HX ON cus.CUST_NO = PAUSE_HX.CUST_NO
LEFT JOIN 
    Fills.dbo.FILL_DATE_HX ON cus.CUST_NO = FILL_DATE_HX.CUST_NO
LEFT JOIN 
    first_fill_date ON cus.CUST_NO = first_fill_date.CUST_NO
LEFT JOIN 
    restart_fill_date ON cus.CUST_NO = restart_fill_date.CUST_NO
WHERE 
    rn = 1 AND rn_2 = 1
```

That query returns this result (Scroll to right to see last column):

| CUST_NO | SERIES_NO | ACCT_OPENED | FIRST_SENT_DATE | PAUSE_START_DATE | PAUSE_END_DATE | RESTART_REPLACEMENT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W125 | 1001 | 12/1/2020 | 12/2/2020 | 1/7/2021 | 1/15/2021 | 1/16/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 12/1/2020 | 12/2/2020 | 4/19/2021 | 4/28/2021 | NULL |
| W125 | 1001 | 12/1/2020 | 12/2/2020 | 6/2/2021 | 6/8/2021 | NULL |

But I need to get this: (Because there should be a date on line 2 and line 3 is a true NULL (Scroll to right to see last column))

| CUST_NO | SERIES_NO | ACCT_OPENED | FIRST_SENT_DATE | PAUSE_START_DATE | PAUSE_END_DATE | RESTART_REPLACEMENT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W125 | 1001 | 12/1/2020 | 12/2/2020 | 1/7/2021 | 1/15/2021 | 1/16/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 12/1/2020 | 12/2/2020 | 4/19/2021 | 4/28/2021 | 4/29/2021 |
| W125 | 1001 | 12/1/2020 | 12/2/2020 | 6/2/2021 | 6/8/2021 | NULL |

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one CTE but with more columns to achieve your result

The first solution uses a subqiery instead of a CTE, i think it will be faster than the CTE, but i dodn't test it with a second CTE which remove all unnecessary row_numbers biiger than 1

> ```
> SELECT c.[CUST_NO], c.[SERIES_NO]
> , CONVERT(date,[ACCT_OPENED]),CONVERT(date,[PAUSE_START_DATE]), CONVERT(date,[PAUSE_END_DATE])
> ,CONVERT(date,(SELECT TOP 1 [FILL_DATE] FROM FILL_DATE_HX 
> WHERE [CUST_NO] = c.[CUST_NO] AND [SERIES_NO] = c.[SERIES_NO] AND [FILL_DATE] > p.[PAUSE_END_DATE])) as RESTART_REPLACEMENT_DATE
> FROM CUSTOMER c INNER JOIN PAUSE_HX p ON c.[CUST_NO] = p.[CUST_NO] AND  c.[SERIES_NO] =  p.[SERIES_NO]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> CUST_NO | SERIES_NO | (No column name) | (No column name) | (No column name) | RESTART_REPLACEMENT_DATE
> :------ | --------: | :--------------- | :--------------- | :--------------- | :-----------------------
> W125    |      1001 | 2020-12-01       | 2021-01-07       | 2021-01-15       | 2021-01-16              
> W125    |      1001 | 2020-12-01       | 2021-04-19       | 2021-04-28       | 2021-04-29              
> W125    |      1001 | 2020-12-01       | 2021-06-02       | 2021-06-08       | null
> ```

> ```
> WITH first_fill_date AS 
> (
> SELECT
> f.[CUST_NO],f.[SERIES_NO],p.[PAUSE_END_DATE] , f.[FILL_DATE]
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By f.[CUST_NO],f.[SERIES_NO],p.[PAUSE_END_DATE] ORDER BY f.[FILL_DATE] ASC) row_num
> FROM FILL_DATE_HX f JOIN PAUSE_HX p 
> ON f.[CUST_NO] = p.[CUST_NO] AND  f.[SERIES_NO] =  p.[SERIES_NO] AND f.[FILL_DATE] > p.[PAUSE_END_DATE]
> ) 
> SELECT c.[CUST_NO], c.[SERIES_NO]
> , CONVERT(date,[ACCT_OPENED]),CONVERT(date,[PAUSE_START_DATE]), CONVERT(date,p.[PAUSE_END_DATE])
> ,CONVERT(date,ff.[FILL_DATE]) as RESTART_REPLACEMENT_DATE
> FROM CUSTOMER c INNER JOIN PAUSE_HX p ON c.[CUST_NO] = p.[CUST_NO] AND  c.[SERIES_NO] =  p.[SERIES_NO]
> LEFT JOIN first_fill_date ff ON ff.[CUST_NO] = p.[CUST_NO] AND  ff.[SERIES_NO] =  p.[SERIES_NO] AND ff.[PAUSE_END_DATE] = p.[PAUSE_END_DATE] AND ff.row_num = 1
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> CUST_NO | SERIES_NO | (No column name) | (No column name) | (No column name) | RESTART_REPLACEMENT_DATE
> :------ | --------: | :--------------- | :--------------- | :--------------- | :-----------------------
> W125    |      1001 | 2020-12-01       | 2021-01-07       | 2021-01-15       | 2021-01-16              
> W125    |      1001 | 2020-12-01       | 2021-04-19       | 2021-04-28       | 2021-04-29              
> W125    |      1001 | 2020-12-01       | 2021-06-02       | 2021-06-08       | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa02425396486416c8e1aea801906f8d)*

Comment: Thank you! Both versions worked perfect, but agree that the first option is best. Much appreciated!!!